# Sewing together flat spacetime pieces = flat spacetime?

Tags: differential-geometry, spacetime

I'm trying to imagine the geometry "operations" here:
[Angular deficit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/angular-deficit)
and
[Curvature of Conical spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/conical-spacetime-of-cosmic-string)

**If we sew flat spacetime pieces together, what is the requirement for the sewing to not create curvature at that seam?**

Clearly there has to be some condition, because in the examples above, sewing together the wedge "sides" doesn't produce cuvature, but somehow at the corner of the removed wedge, curvature appears.

So, more concretely, if we remove this chunk of flat spacetime:
$$(x>0) \mathrm{\ and \ } (0<y<x)$$
and now sew it together, somehow this creates flat spacetime everywhere *except* at $x=y=0$.  Is there some intuitive physical meaning to this?

If the issue is the sharp angle there, then what if we remove instead a nice smooth parabola:
$$(x>0) \mathrm{\ and \ } (-\sqrt{x}<y<\sqrt{x})$$
or maybe a wedge that is completely smooth to zero angle
$$[x>0] \mathrm{\ and \ } [0<y<\exp(-1/x)]$$

Are these completely flat everywhere (no string defect) AND have angular deficit?

Comment: Quick remark: being completely flat everywhere is exactly equivalent to having no angular deficit for any loop.

Comment: @David But Riemann=0 is a local flatness test, and angular deficit is a global test.  Like in the linked question, a path that is everywhere flat can tell something is up with how a vector rotates.  So I don't immediately see why I can't have both.  I guess that is a separate question though.

Comment: @David: that's true for differentiable manifolds, but I think this question is asking about a $C^{1}$ discontinuous space.  You could still have deficit angles in such a space if you take it as the limit  of some smooth curved manifold with the curvature nonzero over a compact support of its domain, and then you let the volume of that compact support go to zero while keeping $\int d^{n}x \,R$ constant

Comment: @Jerry: OK, thanks for the correction. I've seen the equivalence of flatness and zero angle deficit stated in several (relatively nontechnical) sources, but I didn't realize there would be exceptions. Guess I should have known though, there are always exceptions ;-)

Comment: @David: You don't even need Jerry's construction. Your statement is only true if every loop is homotopic to zero. So non trivial topologies will give you easy candidates.

Comment: @David is absolutely correct. There is little need for jargon. Take three square pieces of paper of equal dimensions. Glue them together to form one corner of a cube. This is now a flat manifold everywhere except at the vertex (point singularity) and the edges (line singularity). The latter can be smoothed away by using flexible material instead of paper curved just the right way. Then you're left with a cone. There is no way to get rid of that point singularity. Now back to the cube corner. Draw lots of circles on that surface. All the loops containing the vertex with have an angular deficit,

Comment: ... and all the loops that don't will not. Alternatively, you can draw triangles as the simplest piecewise-continuous version of a smooth curve. You can easily convince yourself that there is no difficulty is drawing a triangle on any part of the surface (even over the edges) and have its angles add up to $\pi$. Any triangle drawn with the vertex in its interior will have angles which sum up to $180 - 90 = 90$ degrees. The $-90$ is the deficit between our corner made of three pieces and a *flat* surfaces made with four square pieces!

Answer (score 4):

The mathematics actually tells you that your second and third constructions are physically impossible!

I shall assume here the "lack of string defects" is equivalent to your space-time being globally a $C^2$-Riemannian manifold. As David mentioned in the comments, for any null-homotopic loop in such a manifold (null-homotopic just means that the loop can be continuously shrunken to a point) there can be no angular defect. (In two dimensions this is a Corollary of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.)

Now, the objects that you want to construct by removing a wedge and sewing up will obviously be simply connected, so every loop is null homotopic. So if you were actually able to do the sewing without creating a lack of smoothness (a string defect), the above will imply that there cannot be an angular defect.

However, by construction, if this object were to exist, it is easy to argue, as in the cone case, that there must be an angular defect.

So by eliminating all the impossibilities, the only option left is that **whatever the shape you cut out of the plane, you can not "sew up the new edges" in a way without introducing a singularity**.

Comment: I don't quite follow. What prevents me from cutting out a slice from a pizza and then putting it back in place? Ok, for a pizza you can't reverse the process - but for a smooth manifold (such as a disk) you can. I just did it in my head five time over ;-) I don't know of any restriction where a smooth manifold can be cut up but not sown back together to its original shape (i.e. without creating or removing any singularities) as long as it is sown back exactly along the lines where the cuts were made.

Comment: @Deepak: My interpretation of the query is not that the you remove a piece and put it back, I interpret it as a generalization of "making a cone": you remove the "pizza slice", eat it, and try to force the remainder together to look like a whole pizza.

Comment: @Deepak: ah, I see, you were referring to the last sentence I wrote in my answer. Sorry I wasn't being clear: I meant "sew it back up" in the sense of surgical removal of something, you sew up whatever is left. I changed the wording now and hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**what is the requirement for the sewing to not create curvature at that seam?**

In Ted's answer to my question, he wrote:
*"In general, you only have curvature if you have to "crumple" or "stretch" the paper. When you form a cone, you don't have to do that, anywhere except at the vertex."*

I don't understand why the vertex counts as crumpling or stretching, but the comment makes intuitive sense.  So one condition is that you need to sew the pieces together without stretching.  If sewing is mapping a point on one edge to a point on the other edge, then once one pair of points are equated there will be curvature if the other points aren't equated with equal path length along the sewing seam.

I'm not sure how to go further in general, so I'll simplify the problem some.  Let's cut the following out of flat space (in polar coordinates):
$0<r<\infty, -f(r)<\theta<f(r)$

Sewing it up we can change coordinates
$k \phi=\theta, k=\frac{2\pi - 2f(r)}{2\pi} = 1- f(r)/\pi$
giving the line element in these coordinates as
$$d\theta = \phi \frac{\partial k}{\partial r} dr + k\ d\phi = \phi F(r) dr + k\ d\phi$$
$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 (\phi^2 F^2\ dr^2 + 2\phi F k\ dr\ d\phi + k^2\ d\phi^2)$$
and the coordinates go from $0 \le r < \infty$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$

Oh god this is going to be messy.  But you can in principle get the Riemann curvature and a condition on f(r) for the curvature to be zero.  (Does anyone know how to make Mathematica or something calculate the answer here?)

Comment: Well, at least in principle this can get me to an answer.  Can someone with access to Mathematica plug this in and tell me what the requirement on f(r) is to obtain no curvature?