# Curved space to flat space calculation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature

When changing the curved space co-ordinate into a flat space co-ordinate if a cone. I got the result transformation that i cannot get a transformation at the vertex(apex) why?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8011/2451

Comment: I"m not entirely clear on what you're attempting to ask here.  What do you mean when you say that you "cannot get a transformation at the vertex?"