# Mathematical description of a conical spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry

In multiple explanations of general relativity, the curvature of a cone has been used to explain why objects fall in a gravitational field, like so:

[image: A diagram from Relativity Visualised, by Lewis Carroll Epstein]

It also appears in videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdC0QN6f3G4) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc4xYacTu-E) from Vsauce.

I am looking for a mathematical description of this conical spacetime. Obviously, the cone describes a flat spacetime, which is to be expected from a uniform gravitational field on the surface of the Earth.

However, I'm struggling to write the metric, because the Euclidean line element for the cone would be:

$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2 d\theta^2$$

I'm not sure if this is the correct metric if time is involved.

I would like to show intuitively that the coordinate acceleration of the falling object is simply due to the choice of coordinates and the corresponding Christoffel symbols.

Also, why does this conical shape correspond physically to a uniform gravitational field? Are there any physical arguments that lead to this shape?

If possible, I'm wondering if there is any link to accelerated frames of reference. For example, does the cone have any connection to Rindler coordinates? I would think that this conical spacetime is an accelerated frame of reference since the surface of the Earth is stationary in these coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Locally, the metric of a cone is simply Minkowski space (it is most convenient to write this in polar coordiantes). In 3+1 dimensions:

\begin{equation}
{\rm d}s^2 = -{\rm d}t^2 + {\rm d}r^2 + r^2 {\rm d} \theta^2 + {\rm d}z^2
\end{equation}
**However** this is not Minkowski spacetime, because the boundary conditions are different. In Minkowski spacetime, $\theta$ is periodic from $0$ to $2\pi$. In a conical spacetime, $\theta$ is periodic from $0$ to $2\pi-\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the *angular deficit*.

The form of the metric should make it clear that the curvature is zero everywhere, except for the point $r=0$, where there is a singularity if $\alpha\neq 0$.

There's some more explanation and intuition on this stack exchange answer:

[Angular deficit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/angular-deficit)

There is also a nice figure on this page:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cone+%28Riemannian+geometry%29

To derive the result you want, you would like to draw a curve which wraps around the cone. It is convenient to represent the cone as a flat sheet, with the angular deficit $\alpha$ removed (so your sheet looks like a pizza with a slice removed). The edges of the wedge are identified, so a particle that "hits" the edge on a trajectory that makes an angle $\varphi$ with the wedge, will appear on the other edge of the wedge with the same angle $\varphi$. If you draw pictures of this, you can convince yourself that the net result is that the path is deflected relative to what you would find if the deficit angle were zero.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the Christoffel symbols do not all vanish even for polar coordinates:
$$\Gamma^\theta_{\theta r}=\frac{1}{r}$$
$$\Gamma^r_{\theta \theta}=-r $$
From what I can tell these are likely to contribute to the "apparent acceleration" for objects moving on geodesics.

Besides this, I want to know more physically, why does this conic shape correspond to a uniform gravitational field?

Comment: @HexiangChang Ah yeah, of course, you are right! I will edit the answer. The "uniform acceleration" has nothing to do with the conical shape, it is entirely due to the fact that the metric is locally Minkowski, so by the equivalence principle a uniform gravitational field is indistinguishable from a non-inertial observer (or, in this case, Minkowski space in curvilinear coordinates). The gravitational effect comes entirely from the curvature singularity at $r=0$, due to the non-zero angular deficit.

Comment: Hold on, are you sure this is the right metric? In these depictions, the time dimension is part of the curvature. In the figure you see that proper time is along the arc length, so it seems that the polar coordinates should be written in $(r,t)$ instead of $(r, \theta)$. In these diagrams, space isn't being curved, time is.

Comment: @HexiangChang I don't know what depictions you are using. I am assuming the spacetime has the geometry I've written down. The time coordinate factorized, and the spatial geometry of a cone having a flat metric with an angular deficit.

Comment: I'm talking about the image attached in my original question with the umbrella. The proper time takes the role of the angular coordinate in that depiction.

Comment: @HexiangChang Ah I see... I haven't seen this depiction and to be honest it is a bit confusing to me since it seems to imply that the time coordinate is periodic? (Maybe this is why the second picture is drawn with a fold... but still...) and also the curvature of a cone is only non-zero at the cusp, which isn't a good model of a general spacetime. I think the basic point of my answer is still the same, you can pictures of lines on a plane with a deficit angle and comparing to "normal" lines will show a deflection. But it's up to you, if this isn't useful I can delete the answer.

Comment: I think this shape is related to how time moves slower closer to the gravitational body, which explains the increase in arc length of the time scale as you move rightwards along the cone. The depiction has been used multiple times in the picture and also in the links I attached. It is purely 2-dimensional, one space and one time. I'm looking for a rigorous mathematical derivation of such a spacetime if possible! It would be great if you could amend your answer along these lines.

Comment: @HexiangChang Well... this is kind of the thing, the geometry of a cone is such that the metric is flat everywhere *except* the tip of the cone. So (to the extent I understand the picture) there would not be any effects like a gravitational redshift. I think it is just an analogy, and there really isn't very much to say mathematically. The only interesting thing about a cone is the angular deficit, if you understand this then that is all there is to say. It might be someone else will come along with a better answer, but I genuinely don't really know how to explain these pictures.